# How to evaluate $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\frac{3}{n}}}{\sqrt[6]{n^2+\sin{\frac{2}{n}}}-\sqrt[3]{n}}?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I tried to get rid off cube root as written below but still can not get throught the next steps. What should be the right step to take after the steps below? Did I start as I should or do I have to take completely different approach?

$\lim_{n->\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}}}{\sqrt[6]{n^2+\sin{\dfrac{2}{n}}}-\sqrt[3]{n}}=$

$=\lim_{n->\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}}}{\sqrt[6]{n^2+\sin{\dfrac{2}{n}}}-\sqrt[3]{n}}\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{n+1})^2+\sqrt[3]{n+1}\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}}+(\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}})^2}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1})^2+\sqrt[3]{n+1}\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}}+(\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}})^2}$

$=\lim_{n->\infty}\dfrac{1-\cos\dfrac{3}{n}}{(\sqrt[6]{n^2+\sin{\dfrac{2}{n}}}-\sqrt[3]{n})((\sqrt[3]{n+1})^2+\sqrt[3]{n+1}\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}}+(\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\dfrac{3}{n}})^2)}$

Comment: Hint: I believe using the appropriate Taylor series expansions for $\cos$ and $\sin$, then for the cube and sixth roots, will allow you to eliminate certain terms, then determine the remaining terms which don't go to $0$ and, thus, what the overall limit is.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Is there any other possibility? As I do not think I should use Taylor series expansions as we did not learn it yet.

Comment: There are basically always other possibilities, including I think with your question, but they often are either considerably more difficult to use or are just a different way of using the Taylor series expansions. As for the latter case, there are a few approximations of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions for when their arguments are very close to $0$ that you can possibly use (note though, as I mentioned, these are usually actually equivalent to using the first $1$ or $2$ terms of the Taylor series expansion around $0$, often called the Maclaurin series).

Comment: Are you OK with L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Dividing throughout by $n^{1/3}$ and using Taylor series for cos and sine should make this easy.

Comment: Yes L'Hopital's is OK, but I felt this was too complicated for L'Hopital's(e.g. taking too much time), I was trying to find some kind of elegant solution I could not find, but if that consists of using Taylor series I better use l'Hopital's rule I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete your approach, let
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{n + 1}}{\sqrt[3]{n}} = \sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \\
b &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{n + \cos \frac{3}{n}}}{\sqrt[3]{n}} = \sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{n}\cos\frac{3}{n}} \\
c &= \frac{\sqrt[6]{n^2 + \sin \frac{2}{n}}}{\sqrt[3]{n}} = \sqrt[6]{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\sin\frac{2}{n}} \\
d &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n}} = 1
\end{align*}

Then, your expression becomes,
$$\frac{a - b}{c - d} = \frac{(a^3 - b^3)(c^5 + c^4d + c^3d^2 + c^2 d^3 + cd^4 + d^5)}{(c^6 - d^6)(a^2 + ab + b^2)}.$$

Note that $a, b, c, d \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, so
$$\lim \frac{a - b}{c - d} = \frac{6}{3} \lim \frac{a^3 - b^3}{c^6 - d^6},$$
assuming the limit on the right exists. We have,
$$\frac{a^3 - b^3}{c^6 - d^6} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \cos \frac{3}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2} \sin\frac{2}{n}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \cos^2 \frac{3}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2} \sin\frac{2}{n}\left(1 + \cos \frac{3}{n}\right)} = \frac{\frac{\sin^2 \frac{3}{n}}{\frac{9}{n^2}} \cdot 9}{\frac{\sin \frac{2}{n}}{\frac{2}{n}} \cdot 2 \cdot(1 + \cos \frac{3}{n})} \to \frac{9}{4}.$$
Hence, our complete limit is
$$\frac{6}{3} \cdot \frac{9}{4} = \frac{9}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, just to let you know I wanted to edit your addition on the last line, however I could not because the edit was too short, it should be $\dfrac{9}{2}$ instead of $\dfrac{27}{4}$  I am writing here so that others can see.

Comment: @cris14 Good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, using Taylor series would make life much easier.

Start dividing all terms by $n^{\frac 13}$ and let $x=\frac 1n$. Now, use the well known Taylor series for the sine and the cosine. Continue with Taylor or with the binomial expansion.

Using three terms in the expansions, you should end with the limit itself.

Adding an extra term in the expansion, you will end with
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\frac{3}{n}}}{\sqrt[6]{n^2+\sin{\frac{2}{n}}}-\sqrt[3]{n}}=\frac{9}{2}-\frac{3}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

If you make $n=10$ (quite far away from $\infty$), using you pocket calculator (I made it on my phone), you should get an exact value of $\approx 4.22868$ while the above truncated expression would give $\frac{21}{5}=4.2$.

Making the problem more general as  in a now deleted answer, the same process would give
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+\cos{}\frac{a}{n}}}{\sqrt[6]{n^2+\sin{\frac{b}{n}}}-\sqrt[3]{n}}=\frac{a^2}{b}-\frac{2 a^2}{3 b n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$